# OGR DeleteDataSource not working properly in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr

I have a small Python script which is supposed to delete a shapefile in case the file is empty.

```
import sys
from osgeo import ogr

drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
ds = drv.Open(inData)
if ds is None:
    print "Could not open file."
    sys.exit(1)

lyr = ds.GetLayer()  

if lyr.GetFeatureCount() == 0:
    drv.DeleteDataSource(inData)
```

everything seems to work fine. The shapefile consists of

- shapefile.dbf
- shapefile.prj
- shapefile.shp
- shapefile.shx

whereas only the *.prj and *.shx get deleted. the *.dbf and *.shp are untouched. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the problem:

the files were still busy from the check if it contains geometries.

```
    ds=None
    lyr=None
```

Setting both variables = None before actually deleting the file solves the problem.